# Storing data in global state

Tags: react-native

I want to store usere_id in global value state so i create global.js

```
module.exports = {
    users_id: "",
 };
```

and import it in post.js , so how can store data in Global.users_id and use it anywhere i want ...
i tried this

```
  Login = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://192.168.6.107:8080/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,

      })
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log("data", data);
    console.log("data.suc", data.success);
    if (data.success) {
      AsyncStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data.user));
      console.log("DATAAA>>>>",data)

     const global= data.user.users_id
       const global2=    GLOBAL.users_id.setState({
       users_id:global
       })
      console.log("global",global2)
    }
    return data.success;
  };
```

I want to get users_id from this data

```
DATAAA>>>> Object {
 "success": true,
  "user": Array [
    Object {
      "password": "ddd",
      "username": "ddd",
       "users_id": 1,
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use it anywhere, create a variable that stores and uses global variables.

**global.js**

```js
let users_id = "";
...
function set_users_id(data) {
  users_id = data;
}

function get_users_id() {
  return users_id;
}
```

**Usage**

```js
import * as global from "filepath/global.js"
...
let user_id = data.user[0].user_id
global.set_users_id(user_id)
```

```js
import * as global from "filepath/global.js"
alert(global.user_id) // return 1
alert(global.get_users_id()) // return 1
```

Comment: Thank you ,,but  >>>let user_id = data.user[0].user_id is undefined...i dont know how to get users_id from this object

Comment: Yes... of cousre

Comment: What is the value of this?

Comment: @amanirose If my answer was helpful, would you please select the 'V' sign and arrow for my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a global variable anywhere like this:

```
global.userID = 3

// and use it Login like this

global.userID // value = 3
```

however it's not recommended doing this very often. Maybe you should take a look at Redux.